# Navigating to route returns Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to navigate the user to /home once he clicks on a box, but currently the redirection does not work and I get this error:

```
 Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

here is my relevant html:

```
 <router-link to="/home">   <md-button class="view-captable-btn"  v-for="item in capTables" :key="item.contractAddress" v-model="capTables" @click="getCapTableId(item.contractAddress, item);  getCaptableName(item.label, item)" >
        <p>{{item.label}}</p>
        <p class="contract-address-p"> {{item.contractAddress}}</p>
       </md-button>
     </router-link>
```

my method:

```
   getCapTableId(contractAddress, item) {
         let address = item.contractAddress
         store.commit('saveCapTableAddress', address)
    },
```

and my protected route logic :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/auth"

Vue.use(Router)

const router =  new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: '/home',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/unauthorized',
      name: 'Unauthorized',
      component: Unauthorized
    },
    {
       path: '/activity-log',
       component: ActivityLog,
       name: 'ActivityLog'
    
    },
    {
      path: '/captables',
      name: 'CapTables',
      component: CapTables,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      },
    },
        {
      path: '*',
      component: NotFound,
      name: 'NotFound',
    },
  ],
  mode: 'history'
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)
 
  if(requiresAuth && !currentUser) next('/unauthorized')
    else if (!requiresAuth && currentUser) next('home')
    else next()
 });
 

export default router
```

I tried using pushing the route with `this.$route.push('/home')` still doesn' work.

Comment: How many `capTables` do you have? And what is `v-model="capTables"` on button?

Comment: 10 right now, but they increase. Why? The v-model does not interfere with the redirection

Comment: You don't need redirection to */home* because the `router-link` itself directs the user there.  So there should be no redirection code in `beforeEach` for that.  In fact trying to redirect */home* to itself causes the endless loop.

Comment: @Dan Someone else may find it useful, no? No posts are just for one individual. They're for everyone.

Comment: @Scratte Yeah, it's possible.  But I try not to encourage certain forum behavior.  This particular Q&A is specific enough that I think it won't be of much use to whoever else stumbles upon it, and I've got similar answers out there

Comment: @Dan I don't understand the argument. I expect you didn't have clarifying questions since you've Answered the Question. Some times Answers comes in on Questions where the author is no longer active. Votes also come in on such posts. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  asks users to **not** reply with "Thank you" comments and states that accepting is voluntary. This author is unable to upvote your post due to the reputation limit. Note: No one voted on the Question.